# Strange results with percentile_cont in PostgreSQL for count(*) per mmdd over multiple years

Tags: sql, postgresql

I believe I'm close to getting good percentile results from a table but not quite there. I've used some advice from Stackoverflow, and partitioning is helping.

Using PostgreSQL version 9.4.18, PostGIS Version 2.2

Here's a query that results in count(*) per mmdd per year.  Using function f_mmdd:

```
CREATE FUNCTION f_mmdd(date) RETURNS int LANGUAGE sql IMMUTABLE AS
$$SELECT to_char($1, 'MMDD')::int$$; 

SELECT ct.ct, mmdd, yyyy, percentile_cont(ARRAY[0.1, 0.5, 0.9]) WITHIN GROUP 
(ORDER BY ct.ct ASC)
FROM (
SELECT f_mmdd(d::date) AS mmdd
FROM generate_series(timestamp '2018-01-01', timestamp '2018-12-31', interval '1 day') d
) d
LEFT JOIN (
SELECT f_mmdd((time at time zone 'UTC' at time zone 'america/los_angeles')::date) as mmdd, 
to_char(time at time zone 'UTC' at time zone 'america/los_angeles', 'YYYY') as yyyy, count(*) 
OVER (partition by to_char(time at time zone 'UTC' at time zone 'america/los_angeles', 
'YYYY-MM-DD')) as ct
FROM fwz c
JOIN ltg_data d on ST_contains(c.the_geom, d.ltg_geom)
WHERE zone = '623'
GROUP BY 1, d.time
) ct USING (mmdd)
GROUP BY mmdd, ct.ct, ct.yyyy
ORDER BY mmdd ASC;
```

**RESULTS**

And this query basically shows count(*) for mmdd for each year. Many years are null. Here's an example of two mmdds. I understand why the percentile_cont is the same number. It's trying to get a percentile for one number, not a group over years.

```
ct  | mmdd | yyyy | percentile_cont 

6 |  726 | 2003 | {6,6,6}
7 |  726 | 2013 | {7,7,7}
8 |  726 | 2010 | {8,8,8}
10 |  726 | 1998 | {10,10,10}
12 |  726 | 1988 | {12,12,12}
28 |  726 | 1996 | {28,28,28}
35 |  726 | 2004 | {35,35,35}
41 |  726 | 1995 | {41,41,41}
90 |  726 | 2017 | {90,90,90}


1 |  807 | 1989 | {1,1,1}
3 |  807 | 1993 | {3,3,3}
7 |  807 | 1999 | {7,7,7}
16 |  807 | 2008 | {16,16,16}
17 |  807 | 2009 | {17,17,17}
22 |  807 | 2017 | {22,22,22}
151 |  807 | 2003 | {151,151,151}
157 |  807 | 2013 | {157,157,157}
400 |  807 | 2006 | {400,400,400}
```

So now for the query that gets close to the answer, I think because I'm only grouping by mmdd in the outer query:

```
SELECT mmdd, percentile_cont(ARRAY[0.1, 0.5, 0.9]) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY ct ASC)
FROM (
SELECT f_mmdd(d::date) AS mmdd
FROM generate_series(timestamp '2018-01-01', timestamp '2018-12-31', interval '1 day') d
) d
LEFT JOIN (
SELECT f_mmdd((time at time zone 'UTC' at time zone 'america/los_angeles')::date) as mmdd, 
count(*) OVER (partition by to_char(time at time zone 'UTC' at time zone 
'america/los_angeles', 'YYYY-MM-DD')) as ct
FROM fwz c
JOIN ltg_data d on ST_contains(c.the_geom, d.ltg_geom)
WHERE zone = '623'
GROUP BY 1, d.time
) ct USING (mmdd)
GROUP BY mmdd
```

The results are getting close to what I expect, but there are two problems. There doesn't seem to be any interpolation amongst the groups of numbers, and why is the 0.5 percentile of 807 "400" when that is the max value?

**RESULTS**

```
mmdd |      percentile_cont 
726 | {10,41,90}
807 | {151,400,400}
```

Do you know what might be going on here?  Thanks for any help, and I can try to provide any additional information that may help. I didn't include all the database information/tables, etc because I wasn't sure if that would help, and it would make the question even longer.

Comment: The `count` should be a simple aggregate, no `OVER`, e.g. you get 400 rows with `ct=400` instead of one.

Comment: Perfect. Thank you!